# SSL error connecting to Redshift from a Go api

Tags: docker, go, amazon-redshift, alpine-linux

I have the following go code:

```
func NewConnection(connectionString string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return db, err
}
```

And the following Dockerfile:

```
# Build env
FROM golang:alpine AS build

ARG stage

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  apk add --no-cache bash git openssh build-base && \
  go get -u golang.org/x/vgo

ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN vgo mod init && vgo install ./...&& vgo build -o service

# Runtime env
FROM alpine

ARG stage

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl openssl-dev
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /src/${stage}-env.yml /app/
COPY --from=build /src/service /app/

ENV CONFIG_PATH=.

ENTRYPOINT ./service
```

My NewConnection function retrieves a Redshift connection string from a queue, along with some data. Which all works locally when I test against a postgres container. However, when I deploy my service, I get the following error:

```
panic: pq: parameter "ssl" cannot be changed after server start
```

My connection contains `?ssl=true` and it should be SSL, we're connecting from a Fargate service in AWS, to AWS Redshift etc. So I think the issue could be related to missing ssl dependencies in my Alpine container, or missing certs or something along those lines.

Comment: You are not checking the error from sql.Open before proceeding to Ping the database. What is it?

Comment: @Peter I shifted that error to be handled before the ping, and it does seem to be the `log.Panic(err)` within the ping that's causing the fatal.

Comment: Can you please share your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

You can establish DB connection without SSL encryption, like that:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=test password=test dbname=test sslmode=disable")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, the connection string we were using had `ssl=true` which worked for a library in nodejs, but in Go it should be `sslmode=require`. I did a check for this, and a string replace.